# How can I make a .php Page which will create more Pages in it?

Tags: php, html, mysql

- Hi, guys!

I am new here, and I'm trying to find some help...
Here is my problem: I have a MySQL DataBase, and in it I have a table named 'Bans'.

On my WebSite I have a list with all the Bans:

ScreenShot Here: http://s27.postimg.org/qj2iqdk83/screenshot_11.png

And this is the Page 1. In my DataBase I have a lot of Bans, and I don't want them all to be on one Page, so the first page, which is in the ScreenShot, is limited...

But how can I make something like: BanList.php?start=20 , BanList.php?start=40 , but automatically created?

I already have this: http://s27.postimg.org/7s0lg7pnn/screenshot_12.png

But it's made manually, you can see page's script here: http://pastebin.com/x2JYyB5d

It's working right now with no problems, but... I don't want to stay and paste the same code over and over again on that script... I want to generate automatically new pages in BanList.php, and on every page footer I want to have pages' numbers... And if someday there will be 4873736252 pages, I want down on every page to be something like this:

ScreenShot Here: http://s27.postimg.org/pxmqlr3xf/screenshot_13.png

ScreenShot Here: http://s27.postimg.org/vn2z62a3n/screenshot_14.png

Do you understand what I said? I really need some help...

Thank you very much!

Comment: You want to hear about pagination ^^ And btw, consider learn from some more updated PHP resource, because maintaining your code will become a nightmare very soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of something like this

```
 $start = $_GET['start'];
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    if($start == "20")
    {
```

Try something like this:

```
$start = intval($_GET['start']);
$nextPage=$start+20;
$sQuery = mysqli_query($SQL_Connect, "SELECT * FROM `Bans` WHERE `ID` > $start ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 20");
echo '<a href="BanList.php?start='.$nextPage.'">Next</a>';
```

Look into mysql escaping, pagination, etc. I would certainly read-up a lot more before pushing any code like this live.

Comment: Huh, this worked out! But now if I access BanList.php , nothing shows up. I must acces BanList.php?start=0 , can I do anything for this?

And how should look some auto-generated buttons on the bottom like 'Previous, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc., Next' ? I can't make them work...

Thank you very much! You really helped me out...

Comment: It's not showing up because `$start` is not defined. Try `$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? intval($_GET['start']) : 0;`

Comment: Thanks a lot, man!!